# iOS 6.0 orientation problems in universal application

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

I have an app that has a `UIViewController` as the root view controller (not a `TabBar` or `NavigationController` app!). This app is universal. It should always be portrait for iPhone and always be landscape for iPad.

I've tried the following, but I think this is iOS 5 code because it's not being called in iOS 6:

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }
    else
    {
        return (interfaceOrientation == (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please read the docs for `UIViewController`. Orientation change handling is different as of iOS 6. The docs cover these changes. There are also many existing questions on this topic.

Comment: it a mix actually :D shouldAutorate is ios6, the other ios5

Comment: Are using xib or storyboard?

Comment: @CodeMonkey: I am using a xib. Sorry if this question has been asked before, I went through the documentation and many answers on stack overflow, but I have no achieved what I want in this specific scenario

Comment: It's alright, I go through the same thing. Sometimes you just get tired of reading the doc's. check my answer and let me know if it works out.

Comment: Could you please specify in which class are you using this code? is it on app delegate? where is it being written exactly? thanks.

Comment: @Jboero this is being written in a UIViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the set of code for iOS 6. It uses masks. If it is for the entire iPhone one orientation and iPad one direction, then at the project level you can set that up by deselection the buttons related to the orientations you don't want. That is if all the views in iPhone are going to be the same, and for iPad it's also applicable. If you want to do it with codes, the the following will do the job:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft   | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

Just take the orientations you don't want to use out. Let me know if you need more help please.

Comment: Thanks! To get it to apply to my situation, I modified the code a little bit: `- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
    
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

}`

Comment: Glad to be of help. Happy coding :)